# Problem with a counter inside a \ul command

Tags: counters, soul

The following MWE gives a compilation error. If i move the `\arabic{count}` outside from the `\ul` command, it works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{count}%
\setul{0.5ex}{0.3ex}%
\ul{text \arabic{count}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\thecount`? :) But, above all, avoid underlining.

Answer (score 3):

It works if you define a macro for `\arabic{count}` and use that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\arabcount}{\arabic{count}}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{count}%
\setul{0.5ex}{0.3ex}%
\ul{text \arabcount}
\end{document}
```

[image: arabic counter underlined with soul]

Often it helps, to register a command for soul by

```
\soulregister{command name}{number of arguments}
```

so it won't be analyzed by `soul` but executed. But in this case for `\arabic` it still gives an error, so I suggest the macro solution.

Comment: I consider the first variant with `\arabcount` better anyways.

Answer (score 3):

One can also simply put extra {} around `\arabic{count}` :

```
\ul{text {\arabic{count}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different from the solution by Stefan, also using a macro and possibly saving a bit of typing. We define a macro `\ull` to replace `\ul`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{count}%
\setul{0.5ex}{0.3ex}%
\def\ull#1{\def\acount{\arabic{count}} \ul{#1 \acount}}
\ull{text}
\end{document}
```

If by any chance you want to increment the counter within the macro use as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{count}%
\setcounter{count}{0}
\setul{0.5ex}{0.3ex}%
\def\ull#1{\def\acount{\arabic{count}} \ul{#1 \acount}\stepcounter{count}}
\ull{text}
\ull{text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use commands inside `\ul` as long as they expand completely to characters; so

```
\ul{Some text \thecount}
```

works. It's really not possible to use other commands, apart font switching and accent making ones; a list of preregistered commands of that kind is already included in `soul`, but others can be registered

```
\soulregister{\myfontswitch}{1}
```

if, for example, you have

```
\newcommand{\myfontswitch}[1]{\textbf{\scshape\small #1}}
```

(just to give a silly example). But, for example,

```
\newcommand{\mytext}{\mbox{xyz}}
```

will give `Reconstruction failed` without `\soulregister{\mytext}{0}` and *no underline* with it.